# how to know if the user has previously logged in? using parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I create users in my app simply by:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser user];

user.username = username;
user.password = password;
user.email = email;

[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)....
```

But what I need to know now is, once the user has been logged in, how can i check if the user has logged in the system before, NOT if the user exists in the database, I already have a check for that, but rather if they have ever logged in before. The purpose, to give you an idea is to customize the greeting i.e." `"Welcome %@"` vs. `"Welcome Back %@"`

How can I accomplish this? I have looked thru their docs but can't seem to find something that would work for me there.

Comment: Why not store a "lastLogin" field in your database? If it is empty then they're new.

Comment: Thats a good point, ill implement it that way ,I was just thinking there was already a way to check this with their built in methods.thanks

Comment: Oh, sounds good. I'll post that as an answer momentarily then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store a `lastLogin` field in your database for each `user`.

If the user has never logged in, the field will be empty (or the default that you set). More so, you can then even calculate how long it has been since the `user` last logged in.

*Note: This is Parse's recommended approach as well ([source](https://www.parse.com/questions/does-parse-track-the-last-login)).*